# When sending UserData to Firabase Database it is creating large nu,ber of copies of the same node

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase auth for authentication using email and pass, also at the same time passing values to database.

Not able to understand what is wrong here.

I just want that it should create a new user with unique push ID when someone registers.

Here is my code

```
public class UserRegistration extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name, school, address, standard, contact, password, conf_password, email;
    Button submit;
    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_registration);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        standard = findViewById(R.id.standard);
        school = findViewById(R.id.school);
        address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        contact = findViewById(R.id.contact);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        conf_password = findViewById(R.id.conf_password);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.registration_button);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PerformAuth();
            }
        });


    }

    private void PerformAuth() {
        String input_name = name.getText().toString();
        String input_standard = standard.getText().toString();
        String input_school = school.getText().toString();
        String input_address = address.getText().toString();
        String input_contact = contact.getText().toString();
        String input_email = email.getText().toString();
        String input_password = password.getText().toString();
        String input_conf_password = conf_password.getText().toString();

        if(input_name.isEmpty()){
            name.requestFocus();
            name.setError("Enter Your Name");
        } else if (input_standard.isEmpty()) {
            standard.requestFocus();
            standard.setError("Enter Your Class");
        } else if (input_school.isEmpty()) {
            school.setError("Enter Name of Your School");
            school.requestFocus();
        } else if (input_address.isEmpty()) {
            address.requestFocus();
            address.setError("Enter your Address");
        } else if (!input_email.matches(regex)) {
            email.requestFocus();
            email.setError("Enter Valid Email");
        } else if (input_password.isEmpty() || input_password.length()<6) {
            password.requestFocus();
            password.setError("Enter Valid Password (length must be greater than 6)");
        } else if (!input_password.equals(input_conf_password)) {
            conf_password.requestFocus();
            conf_password.setError("Password not matched");
        }
        else if (input_contact.isEmpty() || input_contact.length()>10) {
            contact.requestFocus();
            contact.setError("Enter valid Contact Number");
        }
        else {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while Registering...");
            progressDialog.setTitle("Registration");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(input_name,input_standard,input_school,input_address,input_email,input_password,input_contact);
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    databaseReference.push().setValue(userDetails);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(input_email,input_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        SendUserToNextActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(UserRegistration.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(UserRegistration.this, ""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToNextActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserRegistration.this,User_Login.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

UserDetails.java file

```
package com.gov.thecoachinginstitute;

public class UserDetails {
    String Name,Standard,School,Address,Email,Password,Contact;

    public UserDetails(String name, String standard, String school, String address, String email, String password, String contact) {
        Name = name;
        Standard = standard;
        School = school;
        Address = address;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        Contact = contact;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getStandard() {
        return Standard;
    }

    public String getSchool() {
        return School;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

All these formed on single click of submit button, also it is showing no error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an infinite loop:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        databaseReference.push().setValue(userDetails);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

---

Calling `addValueEventListener` registers a persistent, realtime listener on `databaseReference`. From the documentation on [reading data with persistent listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners):

> **Important**: The onDataChange() method is called every time data is changed at the specified database reference

And:

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

So your `onDataChange` gets called with the data from `databaseReference` immediately, and in there you add new data to `databaseReference` by calling `push().setValue(userDetails)` on it. This in turn then triggers the `onDataChange` again, and you again write a new child to it. This continues indefinitely, until the app is closed.

---

Nothing in what you shared requires the `addValueEventListener` as far as I can see, so you can replace that entire block with:

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(userDetails);
```